# Adding reference to another executable with ReferenceOutputAssembly=false doesn't copy dependencies

Tags: c#, visual-studio, msbuild, csproj

I have a solution with several executables in it (say, MainApp.exe and Tool.exe).
The main goal is to ensure that the tool (Tool.exe) with its dependencies is copied to the main executable directory during build.

I used the advice from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/kirillosenkov/how-to-have-a-project-reference-without-referencing-the-actual-binary), and it seemed to work with the older Visual Studio version (at least with some version prior to 16.8).

My project structure (simplified) looks like this:

```
Solution.sln
 ├ MainApp.csproj
 ├ Tool.csproj
 |  └ App.config
 └ ToolLib.csproj
```

Tool project contains App.config file, and references ToolLib project.

My MainApp.csproj looks like this:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="../Tool/Tool.csproj">
      <ReferenceOutputAssembly>false</ReferenceOutputAssembly>
      <OutputItemType>Content</OutputItemType>
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <Targets>Build;DebugSymbolsProjectOutputGroup</Targets>
    </ProjectReference>
  </ItemGroup>
  
</Project>
```

After upgrading to 16.8 after the compilation the file Tool.exe was indeed copied to the output directory, but neither its dependency ToolLib.dll nor Tool.config was copied to the output directory any more.

Is this a bug or intended behaviour? What is the proper way to ensure that the whole Tool with all the needed dependencies is copied to the MainApp's output dir?

---

Added test project reproducing the problem here: https://github.com/vladd/ReferenceOutputAssembly

Comment: Are you sure that this work on VS2019? Please delete every bin and obj folder and then rebuild again. Or create a new solution to test again. In my side, I cannot get `ToolLib.dll` and `Tool.config` files on 16.6,16.7,16.8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you gave is too old and it is not suitable for VS2019. And all your projects target to `net core 3.1`. I have tested your project both in VS2019 16.8 , VS2019 16.7, even 16.6 which all act the same behavior as you described. Only contain the `Tool.dll` and `Tool.exe`.

[image]

So I wonder why you said before that the result of the build of **ToolLib** will be printed in the main project.

Actually, `<ReferenceOutputAssembly>false</ReferenceOutputAssembly>` will prevent the most main output files of the referenced project and its dependency project being copied into the main project.

**Suggestion**

You have to set it as `true`:

```
<ReferenceOutputAssembly>true</ReferenceOutputAssembly>
```

If you want to not copy `ToolLib.pdb` and `Tool.pdb` files into the main project, you could add these node on `MainApp.csproj` file:

```
  <PropertyGroup>  
       <AllowedReferenceRelatedFileExtensions>*.pdb;.dll.config</AllowedReferenceRelatedFileExtensions>        
  </PropertyGroup>
```

If you also want to copy pdb files, you should add `.pdb` under `AllowedReferenceRelatedFileExtensions`.

```
<AllowedReferenceRelatedFileExtensions>.pdb;.dll.config</AllowedReferenceRelatedFileExtensions>
```

**Update 1**

> I tried your suggestion but with it the files Tools.deps,json and
> Tool.runtimeconfig.json are not copied, so running the tool fails.

Add this on `MainApp.csproj` file:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <AllowedReferenceRelatedFileExtensions>.pdb;.dll.config;.runtimeconfig.dev.json;.runtimeconfig.json</AllowedReferenceRelatedFileExtensions>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion! But what are the (negative) consequences of using `ReferenceOutputAssembly=true`?

Comment: There are not any negative point. This is a switch that can prevent the most output files be copied from referenced projects and its dependency projects based on your requirements. This is equivalent to a privatization of the referenced project and the content cannot be obtained in the main project.

Comment: And actually you can delete that node and it acts the same result. This value is true by default. In the default project, do nothing, its value is true. So you do not have to worry too much about that.

Comment: Hm, I tried your suggestion but with it the files `Tools.deps,json` and `Tool.runtimeconfig.json` are not copied, so running the tool fails. Did I do anything wrong? Here is my [MainApp.csproj](https://pastebin.com/f9rPpPwW).

Comment: Use this: `<AllowedReferenceRelatedFileExtensions>.pdb;.dll.config;.runtimeconfig.dev.json;.runtimeconfig.json</AllowedReferenceRelatedFileExtensions>` in MainApp.csproj file.

Comment: Ok, I see, this works. I wonder why I don't see the referenced assembly in the list of references, but your advice worked. Thank you for your patience!

Comment: I wonder what does `ReferenceOutputAssembly` mean and what should it be used for? Is there documentation somewhere? I failed to find anything. And perhaps the msdn article which I referenced is outdated and should be corrected?

Comment: check [this Microsoft document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/common-msbuild-project-items?view=vs-2019) and [https://i.stack.imgur.com/ktEp3.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ktEp3.png).